# can't find the second Activity at the first Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a main activity as:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    final ImageView exampleImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.exampleImageView);
    exampleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GalleryActivity();
        }
    });
}
```

and I have a second activity as:

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                    imageUri = data.getData();
                    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }

    }
```

}

it however says:

```
error: cannot find symbol
            GalleryActivity();
            ^
symbol: method GalleryActivity()
```

how should I solve it?
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: `GalleryActivity();` 
is not a valid statement. GalleryActivity is not a function, it is class. If you wish to instantiate an object of that class you can use `new GalleryActivity()`. We need more information/context in order to help you further.

Comment: Are you trying to start the second activity from the click listener?